# Errora instalar Express

Tags: nodejs

Presento el siguiente error, al intentar realizar la isntalación de Express en un archivo especifico este es el error que me genera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

¡Bienvenido Luis! Lo que obtienes no es un error, sino una advertencia respecto a que tu archivo `package.json` no contiene una campo `repository` (generalmente un repositorion Git). Express se instaló correctamente, tal como puedes ver en la última línea ("actualizados 1 paquetes y analizados 560 en 20 segundos").